# Upgrading to 3.18 kernel causes wireless not to work

Tags: wireless, drivers, upgrade, kernel, broadcom

So I got the 3.18 kernel working on my system (I can boot into Unity now: hooray!). Unfortunately, this seems to have broken my wifi. Wired ethernet is still working, but Network Manager isnt recognizing any wireless networks, whereas it worked fine (comparatively speaking) on the 3.13 kernel I upgraded from.

Checking the "Additional Drivers" app says that I am using the `Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcml-kernel-source`, which is the same thing it said for when I was on the 3.13 kernel.

I'm on a Macbook pro, 64-bit. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I finally got this working. My solution was to [run the instructions I found on this website](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Switching_between_drivers)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and then to unload all wireless drivers using

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 bcma
sudo modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe -r wl
```

and then finally to reload the working driver with

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

NOTE: The "Additional Drivers" Program still lists my wireless card as "not working." As I am currently typing this from my laptop on wireless, I can happily verify that this is completely false